# Does Scala have an equivalent to Haskell's Prelude.show?

Tags: java, string, scala

Specifically I'm looking for a function that given a value will return a string that can be interpreted or compiled and give me back the same value.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, however object serialization may be an alternative option.

Comment: Q: Does Scala have an equivalent to Haskell's... A: Check [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/306910bccec5c74cac2b1fd8f03d1156e3fd1bf5/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Show.scala). (Although actually in this case there's no accompanying `Read`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the built in types the toString() function does something similar. But you cannot use its result unmodified, e.g. it will skip the quotes in most strings (with exception to the empty string).

You could also try [Scalaz `shows`](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/day6.html) which is similar to the Haskell `show` function and has similar type classes. But Scalaz is an extension library, so don't expect the same prevalence of these type classes as in Haskell.